# Rails: Request-based (& Database-based) Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, routes, request, multi-tenant

I am trying to get rid of some scope-prefixes I am currently using in my app.

At the moment my Routes look like this (*simplified example*):

```
scope 'p'
  get ':product_slug', as: :product
end
scope 't' do
  get ':text_slug', as: :text
end
```

which for example generates these paths:

```
/p/car
/t/hello-world
```

Now I want the paths to work without the prefixed letters (p & t). So I restrict the slugs to the existing database entries (which btw works great):

```
text_slugs = Text.all.map(&:slug)
get ':text_slug', as: :text, text_slug: Regexp.new( "(#{text_slugs.join('|')})"

product_slugs = Product.all.map(&:slug)
get ':product_slug', as: :product, product_slug: Regexp.new( "(#{product_slugs.join('|')})"
```

**The problem:**

This is a multi-tenant app which means that someones text_slug could be another ones product_slug and vice versa. That's why I have to filter the slugs by the current site (by domain).

A solution would look like this:

```
text_slugs = Site.find_by_domain(request.host).texts.all.map(&:slug)
get ':text_slug', as: :text, text_slug: Regexp.new( "(#{text_slugs.join('|')})"
```

But **request** isn't available in routes.rb and I everything I tried won't work.

The direct call to Rack::Request needs the correct env variable which doesn't seem to be present in Application.routes, otherwise this could work:

```
req = Rack::Request.new(env)
req.host
```

I really tried alot and am thankful for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use advanced constraints for this:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints.

```
class SlugConstraint
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
  def matches?(request)
    # Find users subdomain and look for matching text_slugs - return true or false
  end
end

App::Application.routes.draw do
  match :product_slug => "products#index", :constraints => SlugConstraint.new(:product)
  match :tag_slug => "tags#index", :constraints => SlugConstraint.new(:tag)
end
```

BTW - You may run into problems with testing, but that's another issue...

Comment: Thanks alot, it works great! I even tried using _advanced constraints_, but couldn't think of using the passed request information for the domain query AND the slugs...